# will performFetchWithCompletionHandler get called if the app got removed from background in iOS?

Tags: ios, background-process

I have gone through various tutorials on making an API call when the app is running in background using `performFetchWithCompletionHandler`. It works fine and I have seen the results.

But the issue here is, it works only if the app is running in the background and it doesn't work if the app is removed from background.

So my question is: is it possible to make any background fetch or API call when the app gets removed from background?

Answer (score 0):

try to implement:

```
 - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: Hi, applicationWillTerminate will get called before app gets removed from background, but how could app makes an API call after getting removed from background?

Comment: What call do you wanna make?
I think you need to do it by push notification somehow.
Once the application terminates it doesn't have any 'dialog' with the operating system

Comment: After you app is removed it is not longer running... so there won't be anymore calls.

Comment: what I am trying to do is: I wanna send one message saying "I am alive" to server for each 10 minutes when the app is in background.For this I have to make one API call to server which is working working fine if the app is running in the background. The issue is, if the app gets removed from background, it's not making any API call.So, is it possible to make an API call if the app gets removed from background?

Comment: No. You'll need to test the communication from the server.
You can simple send a: "I am dead" call from the application once the applicationWillTerminate function is called and act accoedingly